# Postfix Mail Sending Delay

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

Is there any way to configure delay in sending mails thru Postfix server (ubuntu 10.04Lts), what I'm trying to limit sending mail to 60 mails/min or 1 mail in 1Sec.

Comment: Are you trying to rate-limit globally or per user?

Comment: rate-limit globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Policyd/cluebringer

http://www.policyd.org/

Answer (score 1):

Policyd mentioned by mangia is better complete solution to throttle all dispatches.

In postfix however you can throttle delivery per destination with:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_destination_rate_delay

Add `smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1m` for a minute gap between each delivery.

Answer (score 1):

What goal are you trying to achieve ?

Global rate limiting is almost never the right solution.